# Ethereum Blockchain: testnet environment setup

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

In way to skip the need of trusting a third party and to skip the full download of the blockchain on my PC, I would like to setup a full node syncing an ethereum testnet blockchain on a local server and then connect my PC to this server, using a geth instance.
Is that possible in some way? 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just connect to your local geth server via rpc

```
geth attach http://host:port
```

[There](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) you can read about geth's rpc apis

You can start rpc listener with this command on your geth server after or during syncing

```
admin.startRPC(host, port, cors, apis)
```

As an alternative you can just use light sync on your main pc so you won't need to download full blockchain

```
geth --light
```

But it depends on what you gonna do with it

Answer (score 0):

For others having problem with syncing. I think it's a good idea [ for development and testing ] to setup the ethereum blockchain locally instead of connecting with any testnet or the mainnet.

Reference: 
https://nodejsera.com/blockchain/how-to-start-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-network.html